# From where should you run python setup.py install

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a RHEL server.  I am trying to install the python requests module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/).

I don't have pip installed.  But I do have setuptools installed.  After installing the source (requests-2.13.0.tar.gz from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads), I used 'python setup.py install' to install the module.  I did this, and it installed successfully in that I was able to start python, and import requests successfully.

HOWEVER, I believe python will/did source the requests module from where I ran 'python setup.py install'.  Which was in /tmp/.  So when I deleted /tmp/requests-2.13.0 as a cleanup task, I lost the ability to import requests.

Where is the proper directory from which to run 'python setup.py install' on a source package?

Comment: When you installed, did it say it was successful? Simply running the python shell from the directory with `setup.py` in it isn't sufficient as that will import from the `requests` subdirectory in the current working directory.

Comment: You should have gotten a Permission denied error unless you were running as root. By default, `setup.py` will try to install to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` and regular users do not have write rights there.

Comment: Hello? Normally one does `sudo python setup.py install` or `python setup.py install --user` to avoid errors.

Comment: Hello.  I did run 'sudo python setup.py install'.

Comment: Should I be able to delete the /tmp installation files after running setup.py? This part was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using?
If it is a relatively new version, you can get **pip** with the following steps.

```
$ python -m ensurepip
$ pip install requests
```

or

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
$ pip install requests
```

**pip** is an official package manager, it is better to make it available.

Comment: It is 2.6, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

All packages are usually installed inside site-packages when you use pip to install them. This folder can be found inside your python installation folder.
Ex. For a windows machine:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Extract the tar inside this folder and run setup.py.

Comment: OP is using a Redhat server. Extracting into the `site-packages` directory is not a good idea - this confuses temporary installation files with permanent installed files. Extracting to /tmp and using `setup.py` is the normal way to do things. This is not.

Comment: Hello tdelaney - Should I be able to delete the /tmp installation files after running setup.py?  This part was unclear.